# How to take a screenshot in windows 10 when there is an extra pop up on desktop

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I used pyautogui and PIL to capture screenshot after clicking on battery icon. But the screenshot doesn't contain battery status window. When I use print-screen key, status window is available in the screenshot. Need suggestions to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use greenshot opensource tool for windows, using hotkey you can take almost anything as a screenshot.

Comment: I'm not sure how greenshot can be implemented using python script

Answer (score 0):

I think PrintScreen is best for taking screenshots on windows 10. But if you want to use any third-party apps for taking screenshots then **pick-pick** is a free and good app. It also allows you to take a fullscreen screenshot.